# Carousel first issues in first load

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, owl-carousel-2

i have a problem with carousel image banner slider. In first load my page is looks like this

[image]
Looks there are three consecutive images when i load page (those images should be banner slide). But after a moments (less than a second) three images are rendered in proper way. After a moment here is the view of web page 
[image]

The problem is i want at first load web page i want a state looks like second image. Anyone know the problem ? i had just debugged via chrome debugger and nothing wrong with my javascript, could you give me any clue what is wrong with ?

Comment: Bro, you need to share your working code example. Screenshots won't help us

Comment: its because of the ordering of your *CSS* and *JS* files of *carousel*

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay the problem is when i push my code on server it looks like my javacript is being minified so i can trace my javascript code

Comment: @JaisAnasrullohJa'fari any Link/URL?